# Include spaces while reading CSV file

Tags: csv

I have an old server running PHP 5.2. I want to migrate it to a server that uses PHP 5.4

One of my scripts is reading a csv file and the results are different.
I have a line like this in the CSV:

```
Id, Date, Description
```

On my old server this returns an array:

```
array('Id', 'Date', 'Description');
```

On my new server I get this:

```
array('Id', ' Date', ' Description');
```

Which is causing bugs. Now technically I could go in every row, and trim the spaces, but I have files with about 500,000 lines, and adding a simple process might slow down the code.

I was wondering, is there a way to make the new server act as the old one ? (without downgrading PHP obviously)

EDIT: Here is the script itself:

```
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES["csvfile"]["tmp_name"], 'r')) !== FALSE) {
     while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
     if (!$header)
            $header = $row;
     else
            $filec[] = array_combine($header, $row);
     }
     fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

- Encode the csv file as UTF-8
- Preprocess the csv file